# Pandas - apply & lambda with a condition and input from a function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

Need to use lambda & apply for the below pseudo code. I'm struck at else part of implementing it and looping over the DF and creating a new one as more syntax issues being encountured.

Thanks in advance.

```
DataFrame [df]
a    b    c   d    e    f
100  10   1   www  qqq  1/1/2020
200  20   2   eee  rrr  2/1/2020
300  30   3   ttt  yyy  3/1/2020
400  40   4   uuu  iii  4/1/2020
500  50   5   ooo  ppp  5/1/2020 

def func(x,y):
   for i, r in df.iterrows():
      df_new = df[df['a'].isin(x)]
      if df['b'] <= y:
         df_new['newcolumn1'] = df['b']
         df_new['newcolumn2'] = df['c']
         df_new['newcolumn3'] = df['d']
         df_new['newcolumn4'] = df['e']
         df_new['newcolumn5'] = df['f']
         df_new['newcolumn6'] = y - df['b']
      else:
         continue 
 return df;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no reason to use any explicit loop nor `apply` here:

```
def func(x, y):
    df_new = df[df['a'].isin(x)]
    df2 = df_new.loc[df_new['b'] <= y, df.columns[1:]]
    df2.columns = ['newcolumn' + str(i) for i in range(1,6)]
    df2['newcolumn6'] = y - df_new['b']
    df2 = df2.astype('object')    # avoid conversion of int to float with NaN
    return pd.concat([df_new, df2], axis=1)
```

Demo:

```
func([100, 300], 25)
```

gives:

```
     a   b  c    d    e         f newcolumn1 newcolumn2 newcolumn3 newcolumn4 newcolumn5 newcolumn6
0  100  10  1  www  qqq  1/1/2020         10          1        www        qqq   1/1/2020         15
2  300  30  3  ttt  yyy  3/1/2020        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. Will check out the logic, how would the performance be on a million rows?

Comment: It will depend on the performance of the computer ;-) ... More seriously, it will take some time but as everything is fully vectorized, far less than any `apply` or `iterrows` based way.

Answer (score 1):

```
y=20
new_df = df[df['b'] >= y]
new_df['newcolumn6'] = new_df['b'].apply(lambda x: y-x)
```

Output

```
     a   b  c    d    e         f  newcolumn6
1  200  20  2  eee  rrr  2/1/2020           0
2  300  30  3  ttt  yyy  3/1/2020         -10
3  400  40  4  uuu  iii  4/1/2020         -20
4  500  50  5  ooo  ppp  5/1/2020         -30
```

Comment: No reason I can see to even use `apply` here, why not just `new_df['newcolumn6'] = new_df['b']-y`?

Comment: I believe he's going for y-b, not b-y

Comment: right, then `new_df['newcolumn6'] = y-new_df['b']`; it's still vectorized rather than iterative like apply

Comment: Actually i want to pass (x,y) in the func which are a and a value of b, which will go in a loop and will return a new dataframe.

Comment: @Raghu: you failed to show how you want to use `x` but the rationale of this answer is that you should avoid Python loops and `apply` if you can. Pandas and numpy use C routines and their inner loops are much faster than Python ones.

Comment: oh. Thanks @SergeBallesta. I did inculde the code, where x is being used to filter the dataframe. i.e I had a rewrite a sql code logic in python as the code is not compatable in Redshift as of now.